# Filtering products via pre_get_posts by min and max price (use the product VARIATION set via default_attribute for filter results)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a list of products and currently I am implementing various filter functionalities.

Each product has 12 variations assigned to it and every variation has a different price assigned to it.

Each product has the 'cheapest' variation defined as default (via the default attributes property of the product)

I want to adapt the wordpress query in the **pre_get_posts action** to match only products **between a max and a min price** - **however**, looking at the postmeta I see that for every variation of a product there is an entry - e.g.

```
product_id: 10, _price: 100 (-> default variation)
product_id: 10, _price: 110
product_id: 10, _price: 120
product_id: 11, _price: 110 (-> default variation)
product_id: 11, _price: 120
product_id: 11, _price: 130
```

....

if I do something like this:

```
    $currentMetaQuery = $query->get('meta_query');

    $currentMetaQuery[] = [
        'key' => '_price',
        'value' => array($minMax['min'], $minMax['max']),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    ];

    $query->set('meta_query', $currentMetaQuery);
```

with a min 110 and a max of 200 I get the products with the IDs 10 and 11 (as both products contain variations which would match the filter query)

hower:
**I want the default variations to be the base for the filtering** meaning -> the query above should return only the product with the ID 11.

So the query should actually be something like:
*restrict query to products where the product's default variation has a price which is between min and max*...

does anybody have an idea how to do that ?

Thanks for any input or solutions which you could show me !

Answer (score 1):

Nearly forgot this one - due to the fact that the 'cheapest' variation is defined default I adapted the current query via the post__in property to match only products in the required range

```
        $sql = "SELECT product_id FROM {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} WHERE min_price BETWEEN %d AND %d";
        $queryString = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $minMax['min'], $minMax['max']);
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($queryString, ARRAY_N);

        if (!is_array($result)) {
            return;
        }

        $flatProductIds = array_unique(
            array_map(function($item) {
                return $item[0];
            }, $result)
        );

        if (empty($flatProductIds)) {
            $flatProductIds = [-1]; // Passing an empty array to post__in will return has_posts() as true (and all posts will be returned)
        }

        // restrict query to post matching the price selection
        $query->set('post__in', $flatProductIds);
```